# ¿Cómo añadir nuevos datos en la propiedad de un Item de DynamoDB sin borrar los datos anteriores?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, aws, dynamodb

Actualmente estoy utilizando el siguiente código para añadir la string `srcPhoto` dentro de la propiedad `photos` de un item en particular de mi tabla en DynamoDB.

```js
let scanningParameters = {
        Key: {
            "site": folderName
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set photos = :photos",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":photos": [
             srcPhoto
             ]
        },
        TableName: 'Galleries'
    }
    
    return docClient
    .update(scanningParameters)
    .promise()
    .then(() => {
        return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }})
```

El problema es que cada vez que este código corre, en vez de añadirme la nueva string `srcPhoto` a las anteriores, sencillamente cambia la anterior string por la nueva. Es decir, en la propiedad `photos`siempre hay sólo una string. Cuando en realidad lo que busco es que cada vez que el código corre, se vaya añadiendo la nueva string a las anteriores. Ejemplo de cómo estaría en DynamoDb después de que el código corra 3 veces:

```
photos: [
     "www.urlnumero1.com",
     "www.urlnumero2.com",
      "www.urlnumero3.com"
]
```

¿Es posible esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucioné esto usando la funcion `list_append`. Así es cómo ha quedado el código que finalmente funciona después de efectuar los cambios. `:photos` es la propiedad y `srcPhoto` la string que incluyo cada vez que la función se ejecuta. Todo lo demás es boilerplate.

```js
let scanningParameters = {
        Key: {
            "site": folderName
        },
        UpdateExpression: "SET #attrName = list_append(if_not_exists(#attrName, :empty_list), :attrValue)",
        ExpressionAttributeNames : {
            '#attrName' : 'photos'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues : {
            ':attrValue' : [srcPhoto],
            ':empty_list': []
         },
        TableName: 'Galleries'
    }
```

Más información se puede consultar aquí https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html